# Android Studio built files are mixed within java folder

Tags: android, android-studio

I've recently added `two flavors` to my app that one would be for the `user` and another one for the `admin`.

**build.gradle**

```java
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

    debug {
        debuggable = true
    }
}

flavorDimensions += "version"
productFlavors {
    user {
        dimension = "version"
        applicationIdSuffix = ".user"
        versionNameSuffix = "-user"
    }

    admin {
        dimension = "version"
        applicationIdSuffix = ".admin"
        versionNameSuffix = "-admin"
    }
}
```

Now building the project under `userDebug` `build variant` I get this:

[image]

There are folders likes `dagger`, `hilt_aggregated_deps` and etc. that contain files that shows `Files under the "build" folder are generated and should not be edited`. As I understand these have to be in a different folder somewhere hidden or higher the `Project` tree?

I've tried `Mark directory as -> Excluded`, but is this a right approach? After excluding I cannot find them anywhere, even though `Show excluded folders` is checked.

How to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

for others who have the same problem, you can `right click` on each directory that you want to hide (like `dagger`, `hilt_aggregated_deps`, etc.)  and choose `Mark Directory As > Exclude`